# print line in f1 in specific field off f2 and change extension

Tags: awk

Trying to use `awk` to use each line in `f1` to populate specific fields in `f2` (id1 and id2). If the first line of `f1` is printed in the `id1` field, then it is also printed in
`id2`, but the extension changes from .`txt` to `.csv`. The below `awk` does execute, but it only seems to print the `id1` and `id2` lines, not the text above or below.

**f1**

```
/path/to/file1.txt
/path/to/file2.txt
/path/to/file3.txt
```

**f2**

```
#...
 ...
id1=
id1=
id1=
id2=
id2=
id2=
...
```

**desired**

```
#...
...
...
id1=/path/to/file1.txt
id1=/path/to/file2.txt
id1=/path/to/file3.txt
id2=/path/to/file1/csv
id2=/path/to/file2.csv
id2=/path/to/file3.csv
...
```

**awk**

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0; next}
  {print "id1=" a[FNR];
    print "id2=" gensub(/\.txt$/, ".csv", "g", a[FNR])}' f1 f2
```

Comment: Does **[this](https://replit.com/@msankrit/ExaltedLivelyPredictions#main.sh)** help?

Comment: Do you REALLY want a) `id2=/path/to/file1/csv` (`/` instead of `.` before `csv`) in the output? b) `/path/to/file.txt` from the input to become `/path/to/file1.txt` (`1` added) in the output? Please [edit] your question to fix mistakes and/or clarify requirements.

Comment: sorry for the typo, I corrected it but you already guessed correctly! Sorry again and  thank you :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that Awk processes one line at a time. Your `NR==FNR` condition matches when it is reading the first file, and does what you want. But the second action is taken unconditionally, and does not try to print anything else than the matrix of `id1` and `id2` values.

My proposal would be to refactor this to print all lines except the `id1=` and `id2=` ones, and print out the entire matrix when you see the first one of these.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[++n]=$0; next}
  /^id1=/ && !printed {
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        print "id1=" a[i]
        sub(/\.txt$/, ".csv", a[i])
        print "id2=" a[i]
    }
    printed=1}
  !/^id[12]=/' f1 f2
```

The last condition prints lines which are not `id1=` or `id2=` ones. The addition of the `printed` variable ensures that you only print one instance of the matrix. We use `n` to keep track of how many lines there are in `a`, instead of tying anything to the current line number (which could well be out of whack if the number of lines before the first `id1=` line is unpredictable).

Demo: https://ideone.com/pfbVZ5

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't REALLY want the output to contain:

- `file1.txt` (`1` added to `file.txt` from the input)
- `file1/csv` (same again plus `/` instead of `.` before csv)

then using any awk:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { split("txt csv png jpeg",sfxs) }
    NR==FNR {
        files[++numFiles] = substr($0,1,match($0,/\.[^.]*$/))
        next
    }
    $0 != prev { sfx=sfxs[++numSfxs]; prev=$0 }
    { print $0 files[((FNR-1) % numFiles)+1] sfx }
' f1 f2
id1=/path/to/file.txt
id1=/path/to/file2.txt
id1=/path/to/file3.txt
id2=/path/to/file.csv
id2=/path/to/file2.csv
id2=/path/to/file3.csv
id3=/path/to/file.png
id3=/path/to/file2.png
id3=/path/to/file3.png
id4=/path/to/file.jpeg
id4=/path/to/file2.jpeg
id4=/path/to/file3.jpeg
```

The above was run on this input file to show it can be extended to more suffixes and more IDs if you like:

```
$ cat f2
id1=
id1=
id1=
id2=
id2=
id2=
id3=
id3=
id3=
id4=
id4=
id4=
```